# with $2million what kind of survival kit would you bring to a prehistoric earth like medieval world with dragons, dinosaurs and uneducated populace?

Tags: magic, alternate-worlds

what items would you bring with you to another world with the budget of 2million dollars.

You were given the information that they are not technologically advance and they have magic. On top of it you deducted upon questioning that it is a medieval-like age as well!

You are asked to save the other world. Save their world/race/kingdom/.

assuming you accept the offer

you ask to be given money so that you can prepare for the trip after 3 months of preparation. You were also given a bag that has time space magic that can store things the size of 50x50sq meters. It preserves everything inside in their perfect state just as you put them there.

you won't be able to return back to earth for another 50 years assuming you will live for that long.

Problems that possibly you might face are.

-Demon king problems (Cause humanity manage to annoy its neighbors and their neighbors united against them, the leader of the coalition was thus named the Demon king.)

-Race survival. Humans are on the verge of extinction, you need to save them as a fellow human being!

-LOTResque kind of struggle between good and evil(Some immortal thought that it is time for his revenge or simply wants to burn the world to the ground)

-Poverty(Economic Crisis, some sick super powerful merchant guild want to rule the world through power of money)

-Health(Bacterial/Viral Problems. Do i need to say hygiene?)

-Rebellion(Some bastard thought he should be the emperor/king. The princess/prince says otherwise by summoning you)

-Bloodline issues(You need to marry the last of the royalty to thicken the royal blood more)

-Zombie problems

-Possibly alot more as you point out what kind of issue one might face here

So what would you bring?
What possible issues that you would be facing apart from the stated above?
What kind of preparation could you do in 3 months before your inevitable travel to another world?

Comment: I have added "to survive" will that suffice?

If not can you recommend what would be the right wording for the question?

Comment: How is this opinion based? Acceptance criteria seem clear to me - (1) answer fits limitations (2) answer deals with all or most of stated problems (3) answer is simpler/more efficient in doing so than other answers.

Comment: [This question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30253/porting-knowledge) may be worth looking into.

Comment: uhmm... how am i going to get this out of on hold status?

Comment: You need to state one criterion that will let users clearly choose a best answer, there are to many criterions.  You also may want to split this in to many smaller questions what to bring, how to train ... its a bit broad right now

Comment: i've just edited the question... is it quite clear now? thats the scenario i would like to implement

Comment: @micovillena - this can be a very good question, actually.  Can you give it a try in Sandbox, and we can help tighten it up for you?  As it stands, it is very broad, but I think it has the potential of a very high-scoring question.     http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what may be different here than a zombie-apocalypse scenario... 
Especially once you added zombie problems...
The usual kit would do:
 - Snipers, semi automatic and long range
 - high capacity semi-automatic shotguns
 - Explosives, ammo
 - Reliable off road vehicles (20-30 used diesel off-roaders will be better than 5-6 new ones)
 - Maybe a light tank (70's era, for that money)
 - Fuel, parts for cars, tires...
 - Antibiotics and other medicine and medical equipment, vitamins, Condoms 
 - Paper copies of applicable/useful/enlightening science and theory
 - Radio statios, walkie talkies
 - Solar panels, dynamo-style generators
 - Food cans
 - LOTS of cheaply made steel swords 
 - Advanced seeds, advanced farming products
 - Maybe a tractor?
 - A couple of computers
 - Bags and bags of electronic parts (they are really cheap), welders/matrices,
   diagrams on how to make stuff
 - School-grade books (grammar, math, biology, etc...)
 - Night vision equipment!!!
 - Flashlights
 - Lighters
 - All sorts of batteries and chargers
 - Useful chemicals (glues, thinners, sealers, nylon bags, ropes)
 - Maybe security cameras
 - Locks and keys
 - Handcuffs, truth serum 
 - Drills, hammers, saws, calibers and other building/fixing equipment

Comment: Not to be too flippant, but a 3D-Printer and a power source for it might come in handy too!

Comment: I mentioned three versatile power sources: batteries, dynamos and solar panels.
3D printers would be absolutely unneeded. What are you going to print?
Good ones are very expensive. Just imagine how many food cans you take take with you, for 10,000 USD

Comment: See my comment about running out of ammo. Having bought all this stuff after 10-20 years it is just useless metal.

Comment: @Sam, you cannot 3D print bullets...You cannot 3D print ammunition for any weapon.
Yes, you can 3D print arrows but didn't those exist a lot before 3D printers anyway?
2-3 fletchers with sharp tools will produce all the arrows you will ever need and at a much better quality than a 3D printer...

Comment: I wasn't saying 3d print ammo, I was just saying you will run out of ammo.

Comment: @Sam. Sorry, I got confused with someone else's comment.
About your point: are you saying: "don't get guns, because you'll run out of ammo anyway"?

Comment: Basically yes. in 50 years even if you spend all your money on one gun and then the rest on ammo it will still run out.

Comment: @Sam, no man... You can't skip on one of your biggest advantages as a future-man (ultimate defense, assassination, war-winning, intimidation device) just because it will run out of bullets.
Everything in life is temporary...
Take enough ammo to establish an empire. Keep some ammo for deterrent purposes.
Plus, you'd notice I chose very efficient weapons, no automatics.
If you keep your warfare mainly sniper-driven, you will be expanding very little ammo.
You could, with efficient training and discipline, maintain an ammo economy that will be sufficient for your lifetime.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Still if so only bring one or two guns so you can get a lot of ammo for each.

Comment: no, bring dozens of guns so you can equip deathsquads and also have at least one sniper in any important task force.
Imagine you are invading Egypt with tens of thousands of soldiers. One or two guns are simply not going to make a difference.
40 guns, placed in strategic areas, guarded well and aiming for "officers" will cause demoralization, havoc and, of course, casualties in the thousands per day...
As long as you have a critical mass of a few thousands to create a buffer around your snipers, no army of that era can oppose you.
Since money's tight, stick to cheap but highly proven NATO ammo

Answer (score 0):

Preparations:

-get weapons handling,servicing, maintenance and survival training from Blackwater or any entities capable of teaching me such skills. Make a commando out of me in a single month. 1 1/2 month

-Land reading + Survival guide from jungle trackers 1 week

-basic technical and mechanical training 1 week

-Buy all necessary items 3 weeks

-Close all doors. 1 week

Items to bring

-Fire arms(MP5 x5, M-200 x3, AK-47 x6, Express Super Magnum Shotgun x3, M9 Beretta x20, S&W Model 500 x2 )

-RPG-7(Anti-dragon purposes)

-MGL (Crowd control Tear Gas, Pepper Spray, HE, AP, HEAT, Smoke)

-Crossbow (Explosive, Piercing and rope launcher)

-Munitions (for the fire arms varying from armor piercing, incendiary, high explosive)

-Military Accessories (Goggles, Gas Masks, NV goggles, Suppressors, Attached GL, Laser sight, laser pointers  and etc)

-Lots of explosives (C4,TNT)

-Motorbike x5(with spare parts, and fuel that i can fit in)

-Antibiotics

-First Aid Kits

-Medicine

-Man portable battery powered UAV (Rotor craft, Fixed wing)

-Universal Charger(Dynamo Type, pump action)

-Portable Solar Panel Generator

-Easy to install Water Electric Generator(If I decide on a permanent residence)

-Refrigerator x2 (I'm quite sure I will need this)

-Writing utensils(Papers, pencil, ball point, fountain pen)

-Hand held computer tablet

-Ultra Durable Long lasting Laptop X3

-Printer with lots of ink x10

-Thumb drives that contains all learning of humanity from the modern age to the medieval age.(Economics, Mathematics, Metallurgy, Industry, Law, Medicinal, Agriculture, Animal Husbandry, chemistry and Structural Engineering)

-Thumb drives that contains entertainment materials like music, E-books and movies.

-A complete all weather wardrobe

-Black Trench coat x10

-Steel tipped boots x10

-Gloves

-Japanese Swords made from the Japan(Katana, Wazikashi, Nodachi)

-European Steel Swords (Rapier, Sabre, Broadsword, Estoc)

-Oriental Steel swords (Machete, Kris, Piandao and etc.)

-Rations

-Chocolates

-Alcoholic drinks

I think thats it

Comment: Why are your weapons so varied? All those guns you stated, they are too little, some of them very highly ineffective in the scenario and all of them are different calibers? That's bad tactics.
And a million types of swords? What's the point in that, so that every soldier needs different training?

Comment: i got 2 points for using those...

1. I know them and i have them

2. Reliability 

With only 3 months of preparation i need to be very familiar with the tools i am going to use. Those weapons above that i stated are the ones i am very familiar with... they are also reliable outdoors except for the M-200 then again that is up to change

Comment: @micovillena After 50 years you will be out of ammunition. Bring weapons that can have ammo manufactured in medieval times.